# Do you need to factor in projection into area calculation in Google Earth Engine (GEE)?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, area, spatial-statistics, statistics

I'm interested in calculating the area I have classified of a certain class. Do you need to account for projection to assess class area or can you run the following code and it will be accurate? I'm particularly thinking about areas towards the poles where pixel sizes might differ based on how the satellite is positioned in space.

```js
var count = image3.select("classification").reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: bounds,
    scale: 20,
    maxPixels: 9e12
  });
print(count);
```

Then divide the count number by 25 to reach hectares.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections

Comment: From work I have done, it appears that GEE can account for changing pixel size with latitude, so it is able to deal with projections itself, without you specifically casting one

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine understands area, but that doesn't mean that what you asked it to do accounts for area. In this case, your reduction is *literally counting pixels*, so the meaning of the result is entirely dependent on the size of pixels, in the image's default projection, at the requested `scale`, within the `bounds`.

The general tool for working with true area in Earth Engine is [`ee.Image.pixelArea`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-pixelarea) — it returns a special image whose every pixel (regardless of the projection or scale involved) has a value equal to the pixel's area in meters. So, if you mask this image, then apply a **sum** reducer, you have the area of the unmasked region.

```js
var area = ee.Image.pixelArea()
  .updateMask(image3.select("classification").eq(classToMeasure))
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),   // sum, not count
    geometry: bounds,
    scale: 20,
  });
```